# python logging to stdout in git bash

Tags: python, git-bash

I have a python script with logging that outputs to stdout

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(v_level)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

It works just fine when I run my script on my linux box, but when I run the script in git-bash on windows, there is no output to the console.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've also noticed that git-bash does not print until the process ends, it's really annoying and nobody is talking about it

Comment: @sokkyoku I agree that this is annoying, and the `python -u` solution below does not work for me. maybe some bash magic could solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Going by the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346400/line-buffering-of-stdout-fails-on-mingw-msys-python-2-7-3), it looks like this could well be an issue with output buffering. You can skip buffering by running your script with `python -u`.